# How to create a data set out of this output? or make it more tidy as a numpy array?

Tags: numpy

I have  done some calculatuion starting with two points then mean and std summed with mean
How to tidy the following result as data set such that each two data points under each other as rows and the calculations aside of each row?

this an output value of an appended list

```
[([-1.0, -1.0], [3.0, 2.0]), 2.5, ([-2.0, -1.9], [-4.0, 10.0]), 3.0, ([-3.0, -2.0],), -2.5, ([1.0, 1.5],), 1.25, ([2.7, 1.0],), 1.85, 13.813077881487198]
```

How to create a data set out of this output? or make it more tidy as a numpy array ?

Comment: You can't make a 'tidy' array out of a mix of scalars, tuples and lists.  But you might improve the output by using some sort of nested appends when assembling the list. `[[tuple, scalar], [tuple,scalar]...]`, though you appear to have a 'dangling' number at the end that isn't paired with a tuple.

Comment: can you please show me how to ?

Comment: is there a solution in pandas ?

Comment: You are the one who created that list.  I didn't suggest modifying the existing list, though that may be possible.  Keep in mind I can only guess as to what would be 'tidier'.  As it stands this question lacks essential details